# how to use a multi-selected selectbox in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Table Structure

```
ID Name
1  milk
2  flour
4  sugar
8  salt
16 eggs
32 butter

 <select multiple ng-click="FilterIngredients" ng-model="model.ID" ng-options="items.ID as items.Name for items in model.Ingredients " required>
  <option selected disabled value=""></option>
  </select>
```

How do I select multiple options from the select box without having to hold down the ctrl button? I want to only pass the id that is the highest from the rest, if the user clicks butter first and then milk, then the id of the butter must be returned of `32`.

#### Controller

```
$scope.FilterIngredients = function (item) {};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to do that:

### Using bower:

```
bower install angularjs-dropdown-multiselect
```

### HTML

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example1data" selected-model="example1model"></div>
```

### Controller

```
$scope.example1model = [];  
$scope.example1data = [ {id: 1, label: David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"},{id: 3, label: "Danny"}];
```

Comment: and how do i get it to select the highest id?